# Can you use a custom script to activate a python environment in vs code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to set a custom activate script to active a Python environment, on terminal launch, in VS Code.

Right now, it uses the normal activate script, e.g. `/Users/..../my_python/bin/activate`

It would be nice to be able to run another script that also does other things as part of terminal set up, as well as activate the Python environment.

I know that VS Code does support setting environment variables for a python terminal, but this would only solve part of the problem.

Comment: just edit the `activate` script, after creation it will not be modified by python. Just add a call to your custom script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following settings exist to allow you to add parameters to the terminal

```json
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows":["--rcfile", "path/to/your/custom/activation/script"],
```

*The above settings may prompt for deprecation, but will still have an effect.*

Here are the new settings:

```json
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "PowerShell": {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell",
            "args": [
               "-noexit",
               "-file",
               "${env:APPDATA}\\PowerShell\\custom-init.ps1"
            ]
        },
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

This is covered in more detail on the [Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles) page.

*In addition, reading [tasks](https://v) may be helpful to you.*

Comment: I ended up using terminal.integrated.profiles.... It works well.